# How to get x86 Linux kernel definitions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86

Let's say I want to find the real definition of `O_APPEND`, which is one of the flags for `open()` syscall. By real definition, I mean a number like `0x2`.

[I go to LXR and do a search](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/O_APPEND):

```
Defined in 5 files:
arch/alpha/include/uapi/asm/fcntl.h, line 10 (as a macro)
arch/mips/include/uapi/asm/fcntl.h, line 13 (as a macro)
arch/parisc/include/uapi/asm/fcntl.h, line 4 (as a macro)
arch/sparc/include/uapi/asm/fcntl.h, line 4 (as a macro)
include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h, line 35 (as a macro)
```

However, there's no `x86` here. Why?

I faced the same problem when I needed to look up the numbers for syscalls and I ended up using a [3rd-party website](https://syscalls32.paolostivanin.com/) that contains a generated table.

If I understood correctly, syscalls are somehow generated on-the-fly, so there's no possibility to look them up until the kernel is preprocessed for a specific architecture.

Is it the same story for all the defines for `x86` and `x86_64`? *How do I continue when I need something that is not already on the Internet generated by someone?* I could've looked it up on my desktop in headers, but I use `x86_64`, not `x86`.

So, *how do I find the exact numbers flags and modes are `#define`d to for x86 architechture*?

Comment: Looking at the scripts used by `strace` may help. For example, https://sourceforge.net/p/strace/code/ci/master/tree/maint/syscallent.sh .

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the user space API (uapi), it will be defined in `include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h`.

The `generic` part of the path means this is architecture independent code.